# Solving non linear equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, newton-raphson

I want a int of how to set the resolution (using Newton Raphson method) 
in order to solve this equation :

$$ k_1 = f(t_i+ \frac{1}{2} h, y_1 + \frac{1}{2}k1) $$

I'm using python but I want understand the step

This formula is used in order to compute the 2nd order IMPLICIT Runge kutta methods, suitable for solving stiff system of differential equations. after compute $k1$
the solution of equations is 
$$ y_{i+1} = y_i + k1 h$$

**EDIT** It is an implicit Runge Kutta method!!

Comment: At second sight this looks like a fixed-point equation in $k_1$.

Comment: Something must be wrong in your problem setting. ODE resolution with Runge-Kutta does not require this kind of twist.